# Java ArrayList removeAll

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am working on a dummy hospital database. I have an `ArrayList` that has the combination of all possible times that a doctor can theoretically hold an appointment, and another `ArrayList` that holds actual registered appointments.

```
Availability {
  int doctorid;
  String specialty;
  Date date;
  int order_of_appointment;
}
//////////

ArrayList<Availability> allTimes;

ArrayList<Availability> busyTimes;
```

What I want to accomplish is finding the times where doctors are free. Which is the result of (allTimes - busyTimes)

I tried using `allTimes.removeAll(busyTimes)` but it didn't remove anything.

I made sure that I am overriding the equals() method in the `Availability` class but it still doesn't remove anything.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (!(o instanceof Availability)) return false;   
  Availability that = (Availability) o;
  return doctorid == that.doctorid &&
      order_of_appointment == that.order_of_appointment &&
      Objects.equals(specialty, that.specialty) &&
      Objects.equals(date, that.date);
}
```

---

Output:

1. **busyTimes** =
   [Availability{doctorid=1, specialty='internal medicine', date=2021-11-02, order_of_appointment=2}
   ]
2. **allTimes** =
   [Availability{doctorid=1, specialty='internal medicine', date=2021-11-02, order_of_appointment=1}
   , Availability{doctorid=1, specialty='internal medicine', date=2021-11-02, order_of_appointment=2}
   , Availability{doctorid=1, specialty='internal medicine', date=2021-11-02, order_of_appointment=3}]
3. The output I get for **freeTimes** is identical to allTimes even though I'm expecting it to remove the appointment with order_of_appointment==2.

I am totally clueless on what might be causing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried debugging on the ```removeAll``` method?

Comment: Not yet, I'm already off my computer but I am going to run jdb when I wake up in the morning. I posted this in case I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Well the obvious thing is that you need to debug it :-)

Comment: I think the problem is probably caused by the variable ```date```.  Are you sure they are equal on ```date```?  Anyway, debug it.

Comment: you should at first simply test, whether your equla method does what you expect.

Comment: @user16320675 That's exactly what was wrong. I updated the equals() method to make it ignore such difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how are you creating the array, or how are you adding the elements.

I did a simple program with ArrayLists and works as expected:

```
import java.util.*;

class A {
  int id;
  A(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof A && this.id == ((A)o).id;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("A{id:%s}", id);
  }

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(new A(1), new A(2)));
    List<A> b = new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(new A(2), new A(3)));
    a.removeAll(b);
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[A{id:1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong is that even though I had the date format set up as "yyyy-MM-dd", it still stored the time inside the Date object. I converted the Date objects to strings and then compared the strings and that worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override equals(Object obj) method in **Availability class** with your comparison logic.

I implemented it. please check.

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Availability {

    private int doctorId;
    private String specialty;
    private Date date;
    private int orderOfAppointment;

    public Availability() {
        super();        
    }

    public Availability(int doctorId, String specialty, Date date, int orderOfAppointment) {
        super();
        this.doctorId = doctorId;
        this.specialty = specialty;
        this.date = date;
        this.orderOfAppointment = orderOfAppointment;
    }

    public int getDoctorId() {
        return doctorId;
    }

    public void setDoctorId(int doctorId) {
        this.doctorId = doctorId;
    }

    public String getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(String specialty) {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getOrderOfAppointment() {
        return orderOfAppointment;
    }

    public void setOrderOfAppointment(int orderOfAppointment) {
        this.orderOfAppointment = orderOfAppointment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Availability  [doctorId=" + doctorId + ", specialty=" + specialty + ", date=" + date
                + ", orderOfAppointment=" + orderOfAppointment + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        Availability busyslote = (Availability) obj;
        if (this.doctorId == busyslote.doctorId && this.orderOfAppointment == busyslote.orderOfAppointment
                && this.specialty.equalsIgnoreCase(busyslote.specialty) && this.date.equals(busyslote.date)) {
            returnVal = true;
        } else {
            returnVal = false;
        }

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AppointmentMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Availability> allAppointment = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Availability> attenedAppointment = new ArrayList<>();

        Availability obj1 = new Availability(1, "Internal Medicine", new Date(), 1);
        Availability obj2 = new Availability(1, "Internal Medicine", new Date(), 2);
        Availability obj3 = new Availability(1, "Internal Medicine", new Date(), 3);

        allAppointment.add(obj1);
        allAppointment.add(obj2);
        allAppointment.add(obj3);

        Availability obj4 = new Availability(1, "Internal Medicine", new Date(), 3);

        attenedAppointment.add(obj4);

        System.out.println("Befour count :" + allAppointment.size());
        allAppointment.removeAll(attenedAppointment);
        System.out.println("After count :" + allAppointment.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , I do agree that my code is boilerplate and definitely question example is robust, however some newbie find it difficult to understand and that's why i written it like that.

Comment: your code does not provide an answer. the question already states a good usage of the equals method.

Comment: Hello @juwil I updated my answer. Can you please go though it again.

Comment: He has rewritten the ```equals``` method, but there are still problems, and your answer does not seem to have reached the point.